# unable to fetch photo of profile from facebook

Tags: python, facebook

I would like to download my facebook profile picture, and there are a lot of posts here . But almost in all of them this link is given:

```
 http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id or page_id}?fields=cover
```

when I run code

```
me?fields=cover
```

in API explorer it returns me an image, but  when I run my link from the code:

```
pic_request = urllib.request.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/'+userID+ '?fields=cover')
```

it returns an error: bad request

Comment: try the url you composed on your browser and it will return error with message: `"message": "An access token is required to request this resource.` So you need an access token from your Graph API explorer

Comment: Yes, I know, but I send my access token also,higher in the method. graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version=2.10)  . Your error appears when you try to open link in a browser

Comment: If that's the case, you should use you ```graph``` to get data you want. I assume you using `Facebook SDK for Python` right? The documentation is here: https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: Yeah, that's my case.Thank you. But it is not very comfortable, for example to get profile pic, i used link without photo id: https://graph.facebook.com/'+userID+"/picture?width=9999&height=9999" - and it woks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your current profile picture:

```
import facebook
picture_data = graph.get_objects(ids=["me"], fields="picture")
print(picture_data)
```

will show something like this

```
{'me': {'id': '1141473373',
  'picture': {'data': {'is_silhouette': False,
    'url': 'https://z-p3-scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c21.21.259.259/s50x50/536882_4544368124211_874293187_n.jpg?oh=7e5752d39b74ac394ad4ed727cb7d47b&oe=5A7CA995'}}}}
```

Comment: O, that's better. I want to download my cover photo, and I modified your example to get it: pic_reuest=graph.get_object(id="me",field='cover')  - it works. Thank you very much for idea

Comment: Could you help me once more time? How to write it to a file :-( ? cause pic.write(pic_request) - not working :-(